# convert Seq[(String, Any)] to Seq[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel[_, _])] in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

i had trained my dataset into different models such as nbModel, dtModel, rfModel, GbmModel . All these are machine learning models

now when i am saving it into a variable as

```
val models = Seq(("NB", nbModel), ("DT", dtModel), ("RF", rfModel), ("GBM",gbmModel))
```

i am getting a Seq[(String, Any)]

```
models: Seq[(String, Any)] = List((NB,NaiveBayesModel (uid=nb_c35f79982850) with 2 classes), (DT,()), (RF,RandomForestClassificationModel (uid=rfc_3f42daf4ea14) with 15 trees), (GBM,GBTClassificationModel (uid=gbtc_534a972357fa) with 20 trees))
```

if an individual model such as nbModel

```
 val models = ("NB", nbModel)
```

OUTPUT : `models: (String, org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayesModel) = (NB,NaiveBayesModel (uid=nb_c35f79982850) with 2 classes)`

and when i am trying to merge few columns from those models i am getting type mismatch error

```
val mlTrainData= mlData(transferData, "value", models).drop("row_id")
```

`<console>:75: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[(String, Any)]
 required: Seq[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel[_, _])]
       val mlTrainData= mlData(transferData, "value", models).drop("row_id")`

Also my MlDATA is

```
def mlData(inputData: DataFrame, responseColumn: String, baseModels:
 | Seq[(String, PredictionModel[_, _])]): DataFrame= {
 | baseModels.map{ case(name, model) =>
 | model.transform(inputData)
 | .select("row_id", model.getPredictionCol )
 | .withColumnRenamed("prediction", s"${name}_prediction")
 | }.reduceLeft((a, b) =>a.join(b, Seq("row_id"), "inner"))
 | .join(inputData.select("row_id", responseColumn), Seq("row_id"),
 | "inner")
 | }
```

OUTPUT: `mlData: (inputData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, responseColumn: String, baseModels: Seq[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel[_, _])])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please replace the code

```
val models = Seq(("NB", nbModel), ("DT", dtModel), ("RF", rfModel), ("GBM",gbmModel))
```

by

```
val models = Seq(("NB", nbModel), ("DT", null : org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel), ("RF", rfModel), ("GBM",gbmModel))
```

The point I am trying to make is, your **dtModel** is assigned **()** which is of type **Unit**. So the type of entire dataset becomes the superclass of DecisionTreeModel and Unit, which is **Any**. You need to make sure dtModel is of type DecisionTreeModel, it is okay if that's null, if you have handled the null case. An empty DecisionTreeModel would also work.